# can't figure out how to stop section shaking while hover in css

Tags: css, hover, css-animations

I create a story section which work perfectly. But it have a shaking issue when the section is hovered. I couldn't manage to get rid of that.

```css
.heading-tertiary {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }


.u-center-text {
  text-align: center !important; }

.u-margin-bottom-8 {
  margin-bottom: 8rem; }

.story {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 3rem 6rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3rem;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  transform: skewX(-12deg); }
  .story > * {
    transform: skewX(12deg); }
    
  .story__shape {
    width: 15rem;
    height: 15rem;
    float: left;
    -webkit-shape-outside: circle(64% at 50% 50%);
    shape-outside: circle(64% at 50% 50%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(38% at 50% 50%);
    clip-path: circle(38% at 50% 50%);
    transform: translateY(-3rem) skewX(12deg);
    position: relative; }
    
    
  .story__img {
    height: 100%; }
    
    
  .story__text {
    transform: skewX(12deg); }
    
  .story__caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 20%);
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    backface-visibility: hidden; }
  .story:hover .story__caption {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }



.row {
  max-width: 114rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
  padding: 0 5rem 0 5rem; }
  .row:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0; }
  .row::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both; }
  

.section-stories {
  padding: 5rem 0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7; }
```

```html
<section class="section-stories">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="story">
      <figure class="story__shape">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FJZHe8T.jpg" alt="Person on a tour" class="story__img">
          <figcaption class="story__caption">NAME</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div class="story__text">
      <h3 class="heading-tertiary .u-margin-bottom-8">Heading Heading Heading</h3>
      <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Atque aperiam, molestias ut, repudiandae, nobis quidem illum explicabo delectus ullam officiis voluptate aut sit quisquam ab id. Repellendus.
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I remove all the transition property but also didn't work. Even I need those transition properties so I just can't remove them like that. Is there any fix? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/p35087ug/21/) is jsfiddle link in case you need.

Comment: which part shaking ? I can't see anything wrong

Comment: hover anywhere in the section you may see a little shake. I know the shake is so fast that you may skip that. Can you run the code snippet and carefully look it(especially the paragraph part) again please @AymanMorsy

Comment: `backface-visibility: hidden;` maybe not working for some reason @NajmunNahar